# Некорректное добавление данных в список

Tags: python, list

```
Player = await self.pwmanager.execute(Player.select().order_by(Player.balance.desc()).limit(10))

text = " Самые богатые в казино « Seven Dragons »  \n"
users = []

for i, player in enumerate(Player):
    users.append(str(player.user_id))

    return print(','.join(users))

    users = await
    self.api.users.get(user_ids=','.join(users))

    for user in users:
        text += (
                str(i + 1) + ".  " + user['first_name'] + " " + user['last_name'] + ": " + str(player.balance) + "$\n"
        )

    self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

    return await
    msg.answer(text)
```

Почему в users сохраняет лишь 1 ид?, хотя получает 10, не могу понять(

---

**UPDATE**

```
if cmd.lower() in ("топ", ):
    Player = self.player
    Player = await self.pwmanager.execute(Player.select().order_by(Player.balance.desc()).limit(10))

    text = " Самые богатые в казино « Seven Dragons »  \n"
    users = []

    for i, player in enumerate(Player):
        users.append(str(player.user_id))

        print(player.user_id)

        users = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=','.join(users))

        for user in users:
            text += (
            str(i + 1) + ".  " + user['first_name'] + " " + user['last_name'] + ": " + str(player.balance) + "$\n"
            )

        self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

        return await msg.answer(text)
```

---

```
if cmd.lower() in ("топ", ):
    Player = self.player
    Player = await self.pwmanager.execute(Player.select().order_by(Player.balance.desc()).limit(10))

    text = " Самые богатые в казино « Seven Dragons »  \n"
    users = []

    for i, player in enumerate(Player):
        users.append(str(player.user_id))
        pikachu = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=','.join(users))

        for user in pikachu:
            text += (
                str(i + 1) + ".  " + user['first_name'] + " " + user['last_name'] + ": " + str(player.balance) + "$\n"
            )

            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

            return await msg.answer(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.В массиве

```
for i, player in enumerate(Player):
    users.append(str(player.user_id))

    return print(','.join(users))
```

уберите `return`

когда вы в функции пишите `return` то прерываете ее на этом месте
на примере

```
def func():
    for i in l:
        h.append(i)
        return print(h)


l = ['что как', 'пока', 2, 4]
h = []
func()
```

вывод:

```
['что как']
```

хотя еще не весь массив записался уже сработала функция `return` и далее уже массив не будет заполняться, чтобы массив заполнился до конца следует писать следующее

```
def func():
    for i in l:
        h.append(i)
    return print(h)


l = ['что как', 'пока', 2, 4]
h = []
func()
```

тогда вывод программы будет выводить весь массив т.к. он заполнился

```
['что как', 'пока', 2, 4]
```

---

2.вы берете переменную `users` заполняете ее данными, после чего ее переводите в другой тип данных (не в массив)
Исправленный код ниже

```
.....
for i, player in enumerate(Player):
    users.append(str(player.user_id))

    print(player.user_id)

    users_1 = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=','.join(users))

    for user in users_1:
        text += (
        str(i + 1) + ".  " + user['first_name'] + " " + user['last_name'] + ": " + str(player.balance) + "$\n"
        )

    self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

return await msg.answer(text)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75057/discussion-on-answer-by-twiss-----).